# What is the most concise way in Django to make a modified copy of object in databae

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have got a model `ArticleVersion` in my project which is defined as:

```
class ArticleVersion(models.Model):  

    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    version = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    media_type = models.ForeignKey(MediaType)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
```

When the user fills in the form for this model I check whether the content of version from the form is different and if it is I create a new version. Actually now it looks something like this

```
   if self.old_content != updated_version.content:
        # create new version if content is different
        updated_version = self.article.articleversion_set.create(
            article=self.article,
            version=self.article.latest_version.version + 1,
            content=updated_version.content,
            media_type=updated_version.media_type,
            author=updated_version.author
        )
```

But if I put more fields in the model it would be too verbose. I was wondering  is there a way to do such things in Django more concisely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just set `article.pk` to `None`, and when you save a new entry will be created.

Comment: Wow. It's defenitely nice tiny hack. Thank you for solution!